# Должен ли контроллер передавать логику сервису?

Tags: php

Есть сервис

```
class ArticleService{
    function getList(array $select, string $orderedColumnName, string $orderDirection){
       return $this->repository->getAll($select, $orderedColumnName, $orderDirection)
    }
}
```

Есть контроллер:

```
class ArticleController{
    public function one(ArticleService $service){
       return $service->getList(['*'],'id','asc');
    }

    public function two(ArticleService $service){
       return $service->getList(['id','name'],'id','desc');
    }

    public function three(ArticleService $service){
       return $service->getList(['id','name','text','created_at'],'name','asc');
    }
}
```

Должна ли быть такая "логика" в контроллере, если нет, то как правильно организовать методы сервиса?

P.S. Параметры может передавать через какой нить DTO объект, но формировать то его придется тоже в контроллере.

Comment: Если то что вы привели в примере есть все ваше приложение - то вполне подойдет =) Но вообще тут сервис выглядит лишним, т.к. он проксирует запрос в репозиторий. Если не хотите в контроллере формировать параметры, то сделайте в ArticleService соответствующие методы: getOneList, getTwoList, getThreeList и в них формируйте параметры

Comment: Это просто пример, в сервисе еще логика) Просто дилема:
Если я буду создавать под каждый запрос метод - это 100500 методов. Если будут через фильтр, то получается божественный метод, который делает кучу выборок, под кучей условий и т.д.

Comment: Можно пока оставить это дело в контроллере. Если решите потом делать все же какой-нибудь FilterBuilder то вам придется поменять только контроллер. По поводу FilterBuilder - есть вариант сделать в нем кучу методов, либо сделать конфиг ['one' => [...], ['two' => [...], ...] и один метод типа getFilter($name), который будет обращаться к конфигу, строить объект фильтра и отдавать, а контроллер будет работать с готовым объектом. Сервис в таком случае не надо будет трогать

Comment: @Skywave, окей, тогда как вы сможете поступить в ситуации, когда будет динамичный сервис и со сменой методов?

Comment: @And, например? не понял ситуацию

Comment: @Skywave, я же сказал, например у меня сервис который генерируется динамически, как вы будете действовать. Тут и пример не нужен тут и так понятно. что динамика в главной роли. `method1`, `method2`, `method3`, `methodETC....`  Вы в ручную будете прописывать все методы? А если их будет больше 100ни?) Класс со ста методами и тут я решил добавить еще 100 =))))

Comment: @And Кстати, вот я тоже при рассмотрении  этого вопроса задался этим моментом. Допустим у нас 10 методов контроллеров (10 сценариев), где так или иначе вызывается божественный метод getAllByFlter(Filter); Как нам поменять по солиду реализацию только в 1 методе контроллера? Никак, придется вмешиваться в сервис, добавляя новый метод, а потом вмешиваться в контроллер, меняя его. Если бы было 10 отдельных жестко прописанных методов сервиса, всего лишь можно было подменить на новый сервис, не влезая ни в старый, ни в контроллер.

Comment: @Pavel, это не выгодно когда используются схемы `xsd`. Просто нужно использовать магию и перегрузки магических функций, которые будут выхватывать новую схему и смотреть методы, при этом все указания будут указаны в схеме. Например я работал с `NON-WSDL` сервисом евросети, у них на каждую обновку генерится новая функция, заменяя предыдущую функцию, и чтобы сервак не сыпался, я решил сделать магию, которая сама смотрит что изменилось. Но еврик это еще цветочки, есть и по круче сервисы, в том  числе, когда делаешь свою, стараешься сделать все более логичнее и гибче, чем кажется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Условно правильное решение в данном случае — делать в сервисе отдельные методы под каждый сценарий.

Если сценарии использования описаны в виде пользовательских историй, есть связь между историей и методом.

Проблема возникает, если, как вы говорите, будет 100500 разных сценариев, под которые потребуется реализовать 100500 методов. Такая ситуация указывает на сложность предметной области и на сложность вашей программы для пользователя. Убедитесь, что это не ваша проекция потребностей пользователя: 100500 сценариев означают, что пользователь для разных целей должен делать десятки разных запросов, и это обусловлено его должностными обязанностями.

Если это действительно так, то пользователю можно предоставить один универсальный метод формирования *каких надо запросов*. Контроллер будет получать большой DTO-объект, который можно называть *параметры запроса*, и на основании его станет строить запрос (паттерн *query builder* — построитель запросов), который затем передаст сервису.

Я предлагаю начать с простого решения (один сценарий — один метод). До десяти сценариев (до десяти методов сервиса) такое решение проблемы не представляет.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете реорганизовать ваши сервисы в DataMapper'ы инкапсулируя логику подготовки данных в них.

Например:

```
public function one(OneDataMapper $mapper) {
    return $mapper->getList();
}
```

В самом классе маппера внедряете ваш репозиторий, получаете с него данные и подготавливаете их для контроллера.